# Adding an ::after pseudo-element to HTML Generated in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I currently have HTML generated by PHP which looks like this:

```
 echo '<div class="right">';
 echo '<p class = "triangle-isosceles left">'; the_sub_field("right_quote", false); echo '::after';  echo '</p>';
 echo '</div>';
```

Which currently displays in html as:

```
<p>"This is the output of the_sub_field function ::after"</p>
```

When I want it to output as

```
<p>"This is the output of the_sub_field function" ::after</p>
```

Comment: Please describe your problem....

Comment: PHP seems to output quotes containing the html when it outputs it.  So therefore it will output ::after instead of allowing me to use the ::after tag in my CSS..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a `::after` or `::before` are a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from `CSS` (without it needing to be in the `HTML)`.

While the end result is not actually in the `DOM`, it appears on the page as if it is, and would essentially be like this:

```
div::after {
 content: "hi";
}
```

So to add a pseudo you must use css, try this :

```
 echo '<div class="right">';
 echo '<p class = "triangle-isosceles left">'; the_sub_field("right_quote", 
 false); echo '</p>';.
 echo '<style>p.triangle-isosceles:after{content:"something"}</style>';
 echo '</div>';
```

---

then the result would be like :

```css
p.triangle-isosceles:after{
   content:" -> after content";
}
```

```html
<p class="triangle-isosceles">"This is the output of the_sub_field function"</p>
```

Comment: This was perfect thank you.  
I added echo '<style>p.triangle-isosceles:after{content:" "}</style>'; and it added the ::after tag for me

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add an `:after` element inside your DOM (your current loaded page) you have to add it to your stylesheet file on your `<p>` element using his classes.

like this

```
.triangle-isosceles:after{
  content:'';  
}
```

See this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Of course you can use the php function fopen and fwrite and fclose to add your new css rules.

```
<php?
// This is your after element you put in a variable (like a storage place)
$addMyAfterElement = ".triangle-isosceles:after{ content:'';";

// This is your stylesheet file you open and you put in a variable
$myStyleSheet = fopen("styles\style.css", 'a+');

// This is writting your after element inside the stylesheet file
fwrite($myStyleSheet, $addMyAfterElement);

// And here you close your stylesheet file
fclose($myStyleSheet); 

?>
```